# Emacs Javascript Indentation

Tags: javascript, emacs, indentation

I copied some code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()                                                                                                                                 
                          {                                                                                                                                                              
                            var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');                                                                                                  
                            checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function()                                                                                                         
                                                             {                                                                                                                           

                                                               chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
```

Of, course, this looks terrible, because it indents all the way to the bracket. Is there anyway to get it like 2 spaces:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()                                                                                                                                 
  {                                                                                                                                                                                      
    var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');                                                                                                                          
    checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function()                                                                                                                                 
      {                                                                                                                                                                                  
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to do this in `javascript-mode`, but I just tested [Web Mode](http://web-mode.org/), and it has this behavior by default. This was the indentation it gave me for your code (`emacs -Q`):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
    {
        var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
        checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function()
            {
                chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
```

I use `web-mode` both for standalone JS files, and for HTML files with embedded JS.